# How to better concatenate results from other table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to query for a list of all posts (within the specified range), and then get all the comments of each post as sort of a list or an array.

I initially though of querying over and over again for each post, but that seemed unidiomatic and as if it would cause performance issues. So then I found GROUP_CONCAT. The problem is that GROUP_CONCAT concatenates each result of the query by putting a character between the results. It defaults to separating the results using a comma, but that is troublesome, as it is highly likely that the comments themselves may contain commas.

Is the only way to avoid this to use a series of uncommon characters as the separator? This seems kind of "dirty" to me. Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT E.id, E.time, E.title, E.body, E.type, C.comments
FROM elements E
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT elementID, GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR '|-|') AS comments
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY elementID
) C on C.elementID = E.id;
```

[image: Results of MySQL query]

Comment: Programming languages like PHP or Python can join any database output to various types of collections (i.e., dictionaries, lists, arrays). No need for the db engine to do it. Please advise on your end goal. Website? Email? Report?

Comment: Website. Displaying the comments for each post as a list. I am using Node.JS and Express.

Comment: Then connect to you db, query your resultset, and use those languages to concatenate output as needed by various criteria (i.e., user, group) for client side display. Otherwise, use this "dirty" method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Certainly NO, `GROUP_CONCAT()` is the best choice here. Again, as you have already pointed you can use a different separator than the default `,`.
Also, if you think your comment may have a comma by themselv then you can use `REPLACE()` string function and replace those `,` before you concatanate them like

```
GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(body,',','')) AS comments
```

Comment: What parfait is saying in the comments of the post is somewhat contradictory to what you are saying, yet they are being vague. There is no way to return as an array or something of that nature in SQL?

Comment: @Connorelsea, my answer is strictly at DB side. If you want to achieve this in DB end then yes there is no better way but if it's something you think can be easily done at application end then it's better to move that logic in your app code.

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in SQL and am still learning, so I will go with your answer, which works. Thank you for your help.